# {getPost() does not retrieve reactions' component} & {"reactions" and "likes" with the same logical value return neither error nor warning msg}

Tags: r, rfacebook

[Win 10; R 3.4.3; RStudio 1.1.383; Rfacebook 0.6.15]

Hi!

I would like to ask two questions concerning the Rfacebook's getPost function:

1. Even though I have tried all possible combinations of the logical values for the arguments "comments", "reactions" and "likes", the best result I could get so far was a list of 3 components for each post ("post", "comments", and "likes") - that is, without the "reactions" component. Nevertheless, according to the rdocumentation, "getPost returns a list **with up to four** components: post, likes, comments, and reactions". [getPost](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rfacebook/Rfacebook.pdf)
2. Besides the (somehow strange) fact that, according to the same documentation, the argument "reactions" should be FALSE (default) in order to retrieve info on the total reactions to the post(s), I noticed a seemingly odd result: if I simultaneously set "reactions" and "likes" to be either TRUE or FALSE, R returns neither an error nor a warning message. The reason I find it a bit odd is because likes = !reactions in its own definition.

Here is the code:

```
    #packageVersion("Rfacebook")
    #[1] ‘0.6.15'

    ## temporary access token
    fb_oauth <- "user access token"

    qtd <- 5000

    #pag_loop$id[1]
    #[1] "242862559586_10156144461009587"

    # arguments with default value (reactions = F, likes = T, comments = T)
    x <- getPost(pag_loop$id[1], token = fb_oauth, n = qtd)

    str(x)
    # retrieves a list of 3: posts, likes, comments
```

Can someone please explain to me why I don't get the reaction's component?

Best,

Luana

Answer (score 0):

Men, this is by the new version of facebook. This worked fine to V2.10 Version of API of facebook. As V2.11 and forward, it no longer works well.

Answer (score -1):

I also can not capture the reactions, and the user's name is null. I have win 10 and R 3.4.2. Could to be R version? please, if you can to resolve this issue send me the response to my email

Comment: I had to use the temporary user access token to get info on the users who liked the post (but this is gonna change next week anyway- the page access token is gonna be required from now on) :/